# Jboss linux accessing windows share

Tags: linux, jboss, samba

I have a linux (ubuntu) server running a jboss webservice. I need the webservice to be able to access a windows share.

I have a cifs share configured and I am able to read/write to the windows share from the command line. The problem I have is I am forced to sudo in order to access the share.

I created a user that matches the name of the user on the windows machine that has the same creds. Next I modified the samba password config file to map the jboss user to the windows (linux) user with the correct creds to access the share.

Problem: if I log into my server using the recently created account (the one that matches the windows login I cannot access the share.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I creatd a group and added the users that should have access to the share to the group.